# PHP - How to insert jquery dropdown.val() into mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I wanna to ask something..

I have stuck in sql query that combined with jquery which is dropdown.val()..

```
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";

echo "$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#ddlstatename').change(function(){";

echo "alert ($('#ddlstatename').val());";

$result6 = mysql_query("SELECT companyname FROM tb_company com inner join tb_companyinfo std on com.stateid = std.stateid and com.companyid = std.companyid WHERE std.productid = 1 AND std.stateid = '"$('#ddlstatename').val()"'");

echo "});";

echo "});</script>";
```

I try to make a pop up: `echo "alert ($('#ddlstatename').val());";`

it has a value from the dropdown (dllstatename is a dropdown id)..

but when I insert it into sql query

```
$result6 = mysql_query("SELECT companyname FROM tb_company com inner join tb_companyinfo std on com.stateid = std.stateid and com.companyid = std.companyid WHERE std.productid = 1 AND std.stateid = '"$('#ddlstatename').val()"'");
```

I got error on: `std.stateid = '"$('#ddlstatename').val()"'"..`

How to change the `$('#ddlstatename').val()` into sql query statement?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The php content is server-side, while the javascript variable is client-side. You have to pass the value for the query using form post or ajax

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side scripting language and it can't be use like that. Else You can Make a Ajax request!
Make a separate php file containing the mysql query and use this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlstatename').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "file.php?state="+$(this).val(), // here name of the file in which you will save query
        method : POST,
        cache : false,
        success: function(data) { // anything echoed in php file will be stored in the variable data and you can operate with it like appending it to a div
            $("#mydiv").append(data);
        }
});
```

PHP FILE:

```
$valuefromjs = $_REQUEST['state']; // you got variable containing the value of drop-down!

$result6 = mysql_query("SELECT companyname FROM tb_company com inner join tb_companyinfo std on com.stateid = std.stateid and com.companyid = std.companyid WHERE std.productid = 1 AND std.stateid = '$valuefromjs'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're trying to making orange juice with prunes.

You cannot use PHP logically within JavaScript. JavaScript is executed at the browser level, whereas PHP is a server based language. When a page is accessed, PHP will generate the output and send it to the browser where JavaScript will be served.

What you need to do is listen for a change of your drop down using JavaScript, and send the request to the server. A perfect solution would use [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Just to be clear, you'd have to create a PHP page which would receive the POST/GET request, and then query the database. This would be the target for your `$.post` request.

Javascript:

```
$.post('query.php', {dropdownval: $('#ddlstatename').val()}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
}, 'json');
```

PHP (query.php):

```
<?php

/// mysql_connect()..

$request = json_decode($_POST['dropdownval'], true);

$result6 = mysql_query("SELECT companyname FROM tb_company com inner join tb_companyinfo std on com.stateid = std.stateid and com.companyid = std.companyid WHERE std.productid = 1 AND std.stateid = '{$request['dropdownval']}'");

die(json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result6)));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but now I'm using wordpress, how can I add php file?

Comment: Take a look at this article http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-primer-on-ajax-in-the-wordpress-frontend-understanding-the-process/